# Time-independent constant-Hamiltonian Schrodinger equation solution when at time 0 there's a matrix with mostly 0s?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, optical-lattices

So, I'm trying to model the behavior of a particle in a 2D optical lattice. I've done it successfully for 1D. I'm using the time-dependent Schrodinger equation with a constant Hamiltonian, so $\Psi(t)=e^{-iHt/\hbar}|\Psi(0)\rangle$. But now my equation for $\Psi(0)$, which was a vector in 1D, is a 2D matrix the size of the lattice with almost all 0s and just one 1 (wherever the particle is)... right? By matrix multiplication that of course gives me a probability density that only allows the particle to move up and down but not left and right, as it should be able to.

So, either my $\Psi(0)$ does not follow from that of the 1D the way I think it does, or the Schrodinger equation doesn't have the solution I think it does. What's going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain the bit about matrix multiplication a bit more?  Matrix multiplication is a handy mnemonic for calculating things like $\sum_n A_{mn}v_n$, but it's not always the right way to think about operations involving objects which have two indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you have to write your 2d lattice in 1-d array, and the $\exp(iHt/\hbar)$ a 2d matrix.

For example, I have 2d lattice $2 \times 2$

$$
   \begin{matrix}
     (1,1) & (1, 2) \\
     (2, 1) & (2,2)
    \end{matrix}
$$
and the Hamiltonian matrix element has form $\langle(i,j)|H|(n,m)\rangle = H(i,j;n,m)$.

I have to put 4 lattice in a column vector of $4\times 1$
$$
\vec{V} = 
   \begin{bmatrix}
     (1,1) \\ (1, 2) \\
     (2, 1) \\ (2,2)
    \end{bmatrix}
 =
   \begin{bmatrix}
     v_1 \\ v_2 \\
     v_3 \\ v_4
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

and accordingly, the element of Hamiltonian:
$$
   H(1,1;2,1) = \langle (1,1)|H|(2,1)\rangle = \langle v_1 |H|v_3\rangle = H_{1,3}
$$

Thus to maintain a matrix multiplying a vector. In reality, it increases complicated booking. You have to invent your own way to trace who is who.

Comment: huh, this means for anything bigger than 2x2 the hamiltonian has to have squared the number of indeces as the optical lattice. that might overwhelm my computer. but thank you this makes sense!

Comment: Yes. Life is not cheap at all. Brute force computation in higher dimension is very expensive, if not possible.